# Using template parameter for attribute value used in element lookup fails but locally defined string variable is ok- why?

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to determine if an element with its name attribute set to a certain value exists. The document in which I need to search is not the one which the stylesheet is applied to. I wish to pass the string value to search for as a parameter to a template. The lookup fails when I do that but succeeds when I create a local variable in the template and use that variable in the lookup predicate. I cannot understand why.

I've tried it with two different xsl engines and both show the same behaviour.

The template is shown below. I wish to look for a signal element with name attribute equal to the chars before the "__".

The first one fails but the second one, for which the string to search for is given in the template, succeeds. Why?

```
    <xsl:template name="portIsSigObjOrQuality">
    <xsl:param name="portName" />

    <xsl:variable name="nameOfCompoundInstanceFromPort"
     select="substring-before($portName,'__')" />

  <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when
        test="$signalLookupDoc/signals/signal[./@name=$nameOfCompoundInstanceFromPort]">
        <xsl:text>yes</xsl:text>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>no</xsl:text>
     </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>

    <xsl:variable name="nameOfCompoundInstanceFromString"
        select="substring-before('EssBypassValveAM__sdfsdf', '__')" />

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when
            test="$signalLookupDoc/signals/signal[./@name=$nameOfCompoundInstanceFromString]">
            <xsl:text>yes</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>no</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:text>;&#10;</xsl:text>

</xsl:template>

signalLookupDoc is defined as
<xsl:variable name="signalLookupDoc" select="document($param2)" />
```

and the template is called

```
<xsl:call-template name="portIsSigObjOrQuality">
            <xsl:with-param name="portName" select="'EssByPassValveAM__Enabled'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
```

Any one who can explain to me why first lookup fails and what I shold do to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the difference in caps (case-sensitive match)?

```
EssBypassValveAM
```

and

```
EssByPassValveAM
```

Note the P vs p.

Comment: that easy...I wish I could remove this question from the known universe

Comment: @Olof - it always helps to get a second pair of eyes to spot those issues. It is very easy to run into these sort of problems in XSLT/XPath because it isn't an error to select/match on something that doesn't exist.